# Assigning data to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to know if anyone knows how one is supposed to assign image data to a `cv::Mat` file that has already been created.  It seems that the `cv::Mat` constructor has an overloaded method that supports passing it a `void*` of the data, but I'm not sure what to do once the object has already been constructed (without recalling the constructor and replacing the `cv::Mat`).

Currently, I'm manually pointing `cv::Mat.data` to the data I want.  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do the same for `cv::Mat.datastart`.  I would've thought there'd be some sort of helper function to allow reassigning `cv::Mat`'s data.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the new data have the same type and size as the constructed Mat header?

Comment: Yes, only the data changes.

Comment: Manually pointing the `data` pointer to the new image data is *not* a good idea. It might look like it works, but there can be subtle issues with creating submatrices or even `Mat`'s reference counting. Can you elaborate a little more on your problem? How is the image data stored? Is copying this data acceptable?

Comment: The image data is YUV and copying the data is not acceptable.  This code will run on a microprocessor so it needs to be fast!

The data that comes out of the camera is YUYV and I convert it to be in the form YUVYUV, then I want to store this into a `cv::Mat` and I don't want to convert it to RGB, I want it stored as YUVYUV.  SO what I did was, I grabbed the YUYV, malloced a bunch of memory at which i stored the YUVYUV data, then I just assigned the data pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reassign a pre-initialized `cv::Mat` to new image data.  Here are a few legal ways of assigning new image data to a `cv::Mat` that was already created.

```
cv::Mat my_mat = cv::imread("some_image.jpg");
my_mat = cv::imread("another_image.jpg");

cv::Mat second_mat = cv::imread("one_more.jpg");
second_mat = my_mat.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation:

```
// constructor for matrix headers pointing to user-allocated data
Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
Mat(Size _size, int _type, void* _data, size_t _step=AUTO_STEP);
```

The data pointer can point anywhere with valid _size and _type. If the new data has different size or type, then your header is invalid.